# Scrolling with Compose and NestedScrollView Xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am planning to migrate from XML-based code to ComposeView.

The problem is I have is in XML I have `NestedScroolView` and inside that I am using `LazyColumn`

I do need scrolling since the list is long.

How can I migrate without the possibility of removing `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to basically lock the scrolling of the NestedScrollView when a LazyColumn is going to become a child view.

This requires you to [create a custom class of NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73692075/3814398)

Then simply call `setScrollingEnabled(false)` when you need the LazyColumn to scroll normally.